# Perl разбить стринг

Tags: sql, perl

Есть вот такая конструкция

```
foreach ($cook->{img_ids}) {
        my @dress = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT pid FROM imnew WHERE id IN (".$cook->{img_ids}.")");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $dre = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
         
            push(@dress, $dre);
        
        }
        $sth->finish;
        if (@dress) {
            $dress[-1]->{last} = 1;
            $hash->{dress} = \@dress;
        }
    }
```

В $cook->{img_ids} записи хранятся в виде 7687,7688,7689,741,7669,7458  - так вот, как мне сделать перебор каждой записи (главный foreach), но в самом sql запросе использовать каждую запись по очереди, а не вместе.

Comment: Сплитнуть типа my @ids = split (/\,/, $cook->{img_ids}) и потом формировать SELECT'ы внутри вложенного "foreach my $id (@ids) {...}" ?

Comment: Суть проблемы - параметр передаётся как один строковый литерал, а не как набор литералов. Т.е. после подстановки получается не `WHERE id IN ('1','2','3')`, a `WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')` Простой (но плохой по производительности) вариант - заменить `WHERE id IN (".$cook->{img_ids}.")"` на `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ".$cook->{img_ids}.")"`. Более сложный - искать, есть ли в используемом фреймворке способ передачи параметра-массива, который сформирует правильный вид запроса (при этом, само собой, CSV придётся сплитнуть в массив).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так, если конечно `$cook->{img_ids}` ссылка на массив строк:

```
foreach (@{$cook->{img_ids}}) {
  my @dress = ();
  s/(\d+)/'$1'/g;
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT pid FROM imnew WHERE id IN ($_)");
  my $rvs = $sth->execute or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
  while (my $dre = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push(@dress, $dre);
  }
  $sth->finish;
  if (@dress) {
    $dress[-1]->{last} = 1;
    $hash->{dress} = \@dress;
  }
}
```